# Grunt Dist Folder Relative Path Errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am using the express-angular generator on yeoman, and building using grunt. I have successfully ran grunt, and created a dist folder. Within the dist folder I have my index.html file, which GETs the following files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/74e111d6.main.css">

<script src="scripts/d41d8cd9.plugins.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/dafe662c.modules.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/d41d8cd9.scripts.js"></script>
```

These files all exist in my dist folder, however the GET requests in my console show that it is attempting to GET the files from the root. i.e.

GET http://localhost:5000/styles/74e111d6.main.css

I do not know why this is. I have attempted to change the src to 
`src="dist/scripts/d41d8cd9.scripts.js"`, but it does not GET the file from the right location still.

The project tree looks like.

```
angularexpress
-> app
-> dist 
     -> bower_components
     -> images
     -> scripts
         -> d41d8cd9.scripts.js
         -> dafe662c.modules.js
         -> d41d8cd9.scripts.js
     -> styles
         -> 74e111d6.main.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might be missing [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html), or have it configured incorrectly.

Comment: Yup it was this. Totally forgot about this, feels bad. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

are you able to access this url (http://localhost:5000/dist/styles/74e111d6.main.css) from the browser? If it works, then change the src to src="/dist/styles/74e111d6.main.css"

Comment: No you cannot get that url.

Comment: are you able to access http://localhost:5000/dist/index.html in the browser? (type the this url in the new tab)